# What are configuration files?

Tags: c, configuration-files

What are configuration files? What are their use in c programs?

Additional question: What does it mean to have an error which states "Cannot open configuration file"?

Comment: A configuration file for what? There are literally hundreds of different kinds of config files

Comment: I'm not sure. I was debugging this code in c and it says "cannot open configuration file". Now I'm searching for the use of config files or generally what config files are. I can't understand the definition found on several websites. I am not aware of the different types of config files (not stated in the sites I visited).

Comment: @ChaineSanBuenaventura what code? - it is such an abstract concept, it's impossible to tell you what to look for other than C FILE operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A configuration file could be any file which the program uses to persistently store options, state, or data between executions. The concept is not specific to C and is probably universal to most programming languages. It is impossible, without knowing exactly what program you are dealing with, to figure out what they are, where they would be stored, or why the program wouldn't be able to open it.

Comment: Do all C programs have config files? I can't still fully grasp the concept of config files. How can they be accessed?

Comment: @ChaineSanBuenaventura it's just a file, some programs have features that need to be configured and some of those use files to store those options, some don't. Its not a natural part of the language - its an abstract concept used when needed.

Comment: I have another question, what does parsing of config file mean?

Comment: @ChaineSanBuenaventura parsing is the process of reading the relevant information out of the file. It sounds like stack overflow may not be the place for your questions. It is for programmers and students of programming.

Comment: i think correcting these syntax errors is part of coding. I really am not familiar with config files and I have just started learning c. I coded using a different language before and I was not faced with all these new unfamiliar syntax errors. My apologies for asking this type of question. But your answer helped.

Comment: @ChaineSanBuenaventura A syntax error is a fundamentally invalid language statement. In C the code would not compile if syntax errors existed.